# Pivot table different id

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I've stumbled on some tricky issue that I can't wrap my head around.

I have 2 models, User and Employer.

```
          [User]
        /        
[Employer]
```

Employer inherits from User table. Employers can belong to different Centers, so I have a ManyToMany relation between a Center and a Doctor.

```
   [User] (23)
     ^
     |
  [Employer]  ____________________________   [Center]
        ^----|   employers_has_centers    |----^
             |----------------------------| 
             |id |  employer  | center_id |
             |----------------------------| 
             | 1 | 23(user_id)|     2     |
             |____________________________|
```

**Employer.php**

```
public function healthCenters()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(HealthCenter::class);
}
```

Now my issue is that when I try to fetch one Employer and load Centers with the response it complains on

```
Unknown column &#039;employer_health_center.employer_id&#039;
```

I never use my `employer_id` in any columns, I always refer to `user_id` when I do CRUD operations.

And when I'm trying to create an Employer refer/attach to a Center, this issue appears:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;employer_id&#039
```

So I assume by default Laravel tries to get id from column from my Employer model, is there a way I change so that it should search for `user_id` column instead of id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unknown column 'employer_health_center.employer_id'

This is because by default, laravel try to follow a convention in picking up the primary key from the table `employers`. So laravel will look for an id `employer_id`. Since, in your table it's `employer`, you can specify that in the relation.

```
public function healthCenters()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(HealthCenter::class, 'employer');
}
```

So, if its just the initial stage of your coding, I strongly suggest you to follow the convention over configuration.

Comment: Alright, had to add (class, table, 'employer') to get it to work. I can atleast save now, but when fetching an Employer and lazy load a Center doesnt work.

Maybe i'll just go with PK.

Comment: yeah, just follow the conventions and everything will be super easy. Also, it's really easy to understand the database tables when you follow it.